# fat arrow notation and regular function

Tags: javascript, lambda

Regular function:

```
function square(number) {
  return number.map(function (x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}
```

Fat arrow:

```
let square = (number) => {
  return number.map(function(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}
```

Are the fat arrow correct? or Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you, I did change my question. It is Ruby.

Comment: This is not Ruby. This is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example is correct.

```
let square = (number) => {
  return number.map(function(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}
```

You can also leave out the parenthesis if there is only 1 parameter.

```
let square = number => {
  return number.map(function(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}
```

Why not lambda in lambda?

```
let square = number => {
  return number.map( x => {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}
```

You can also remove curly braces and use default return if it is a single expression.

```
let square = number => number.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2));
```

Finally, let's clean it up by using a lambda as parameter and leaving out the fat arrow.  This one is easy to read, extensible, reusable, and very succinct.

```
let power2 = x => Math.pow(x,2)
let square = number => number.map(power2);
```

A working snippet.

```js
let power2 = x => Math.pow(x,2)
let square = number => number.map(power2);
console.log(square([4,5,6]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. You can test this yourself in any interpreter, including here on Stack Overflow:

```js
let square = (number) => {
  return number.map(function(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}

result.value = square([1,2,3,4]);
```

```html
<output id="result"></output>
```